# Updating textbox within UpdatePanel from codebehind of another page that is in an iframe in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, updatepanel

I have a web application that I'm working on. On the parent page I have a status text box within an `UpdatePanel`. There is an `iframe` on the parent page that on page load executes some codebehind function in C# that happens to take a long time. (Quite a few lines of code get executed)

I was wondering how I could call out to the parent page from within the `iframe`s code behind and do Updates on the `UpdatePanel` at various times in the function.

Here is some of the html from the main page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="StatusPanel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Width="99%" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
  </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And some of my c# codebehind from the iframe:

```
foreach (CorpLead lead in leadsPriority1)
{
    UpdateStatus(lead.name);
    xRMData.AssignCorpLead(agentProfiles, lead, service);
}

private void UpdateStatus(string lead)
{
    if (this.Parent.FindControl("txtStatus") != null)
    {
        ((TextBox)this.Parent.FindControl("txtStatus")).Text = lead;
        ((UpdatePanel)this.Parent.FindControl("StatusPanel")).Update();
    }    
}
```

Comment: So basically parent page hosts update panel and separately IFRAME. And while iframe loads you want UpdatePanel to refresh at regular intervals?

Comment: Yes, to the parent page hosting the update panel and separate iframe. On page load the iframe calls a function. In that function, at various points in it I want to call a function that updates the parent page's update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code examples it's just a guess for your specific problem but you can access controls on the parent page like so:

```
if (this.Parent.FindControl("ControlID") != null)
{
    ((Control)this.Parent.FindControl("ControlID")).Property = value;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: In theory, that sounds exactly like what I want, but when I went to implement your code I wasn't able to find my asp.net text box that is nested within my update panel. I just kept getting a null reference error.

Comment: Post a code example please and we can probably get to the bottom of it.

Comment: After getting into work, I did more tests and it seems that `this.Parent` is null.

Comment: You might have to pass session variables around to get it to work since you are using an iframe instead of an ASP.NET control model like a Master/Child scenario.  My suggestion would be to restructure your page to make them able to talk to each other more easily, but if that is not possible, you could try putting your UpdatePanel in your iframe page and having your iframe page code update its own textbox so you don't have to try to talk between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Since your IFRAME calls a function - it can call a function of the parent page (I am talking about JavaScript function). That parent function can use `setInterval` to programmatically "click" on a hidden `LinkButton` control which is set as a trigger for your UpdatePanel.

Result: UpdatePanel is refreshed at given intervals

Comment: The thing is I want the `UpdatePanel` to be updated with information that would come from IFRAME's codebehind function. For instance, it has a list of objects and does stuff with them. I would like the `UpdatePanel` to be updated with the name of those objects as I iterate through them.